# ExtAudioFileGetProperty File Length return 0 frame

Tags: ios, core-audio

I am using the RemoteIO to save and read a file.
Basically it is stored in a wav format.
here is my ASBD for saving the files

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
audioFormat.mSampleRate= graphSampleRate;
audioFormat.mFormatID=kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
audioFormat.mFormatFlags= kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger|kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket=bytesPerSample;
audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame=bytesPerSample;
audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket=1;
audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame=1;
audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel= 8 * bytesPerSample;
audioFormat.mReserved=0;
```

and I use this function to retrieve the frame length

```
UInt64 totalFramesInFile = 0;
UInt32 frameLengthPropertySize = sizeof (totalFramesInFile);

result =    ExtAudioFileGetProperty (
                                     audioFileObject,
                                     kExtAudioFileProperty_FileLengthFrames,
                                     &frameLengthPropertySize,
                                     &totalFramesInFile
                                     );
```

I tried to hard code the frame to 100. I believe the audio contains some data. I just do not know why it could not read the frame length. Please let me know if I need to provide other information. I am very new to core audio. I hope someone could help. Thanks

Comment: hi Ken, did you solve this problem in the end? i have a similar problem where i always get 1024 as number of frames in the file, but the file is much longer. in my case, it's also a plain 2 channel, 16 bit per channel WAV file.

Comment: Hi Daniel, sorry for late reply. I didn't remember exactly how I solve the problem. But what left in my memory is I forgot to write into the files. Therefore, I just init the file and forgot one line of code to link up everything. My suggestion is, try to check is the file really saved to disk first ! Before going to next steps. You may try to access it in finder with using Simulator. I hope it helps.